# jQuery Destroy / Disable / Trigger Once Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to use IMakeWebThings `Waypoints` with Daniel Eden's `Animate.css` file to essentially, have a `form` appear once it enters the viewport. Once the `form` is submitted, it should disappear and never reappear.

Everything is working perfectly, **except** that once the form is submitted, it reappears after scrolling up and down the page. I'm trying to either `destroy` or `triggerOnce` the waypoint after it completes the first time, but i'm not having any luck.

Some searches have led me to learn that these `.destroy`, etc. are JavaScript only methods but is there anyway to accomplish this with what I have already or do I need to rewrite it?

Waypoint:

```
    $('#contactForm').waypoint(function() {

      $('#contactForm').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
        $('#contactForm').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
      });

      }, {
      triggerOnce: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah it was a simple fix.

```
$('#contactForm').waypoint(function() {

  $('#contactForm').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $('#contactForm').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
  });
  this.destroy();
  }, {
  triggerOnce: true
});
```

Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643069/use-destroy-with-waypoints-but-only-on-one-object)